# C# for CSV import: array or datatable or something else?

Tags: c#, arrays, csv, struct

I've already written some code in VBA/Excel to analyse IQ RF data by importing a CSV file into Excel then doing "stuff" with it. But it's slow I can can only get just over 10^6 lines in at once. So I'm re-writing it using C#, but I'm only a newbie to C#/VS so on a big learning curve...

Should I try to put my 64x10^6 lines into some kind of database, into a 2-dimensional array, struct, or some other kind of data structure? Any limits/benefits I should know about?

(The plan is to then calculate the log of the sum of squares of those 2 'columns' for every data point to find amplitude, and add a time 'column'. Once that's done I'll then be working out start and stop times of events based on amplitude and will end up with another new dataset from them on which analysis will continue.)

Comment: You can also use [LocalDB](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-an-improved-sql-express/) which is simpler version of SQL Express. You should try relational database at this point.

Comment: Thanks I'll go googling all the suggestions here. It's hard to know what to look for to start out with, so any suggestion will help get me exploring the right possible avenues. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like any relational database would work here. Since you're working in .NET the simplest way would be to use Sql Server Express. See: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express
Keep in mind that it has a 10Gb database size limit.

Comment: Thanks. I'll go investigate. I may also go with mbmcavoys idea of simple arrays, but move the analysis results from the initial dataset into a database as there will be a lot more columns and details produced by that. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may even be able to do without any c# and do this solely in SQL - it has the ability to perform calculations and conditional actions, also you can import CSV data directly into a table.
There's plenty of examples if you google ;) (ie, for your log calculation search for 'LOG (Transact-SQL)')

Comment: It'll end up using C/.net libraries for instrument hardware control and data capture later once it gets jazzed up though... :-/

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like your data is a numerical series (value over time), and that you do not need additional long-term storage of that data, but rather a means of processing the data to provide a report.

Assuming you have sufficient memory available, It is probably simplest just to use arrays and loop through them. This is a much smaller learning curve than using a database, and you won't need the higher functions that a database can provide.

However, memory can be an issue if your input is extremely large. You may be able to reduce the in-work data if you can chop the data into smaller chunks. I.e., read the first 1000 data points, process them, then reload the array with the next 1000 data points.

As another thought - Where did this data come from? The question implies a recorded data set. perhaps the source also provides tools for working with the data.

As an example, I have worked with a laboratory data acquisition system that recorded ~600 channels at 5KHz; the raw files were massive and in a proprietary format. There were ways of exporting data to CSV or other generic formats, but they were difficult to work with due the the file sizes, and the export process itself was tedious. The manufacturer provided a DLL "toolkit" library compatible with C# that I was able to use to open and read the native files, with relative ease.

Comment: Yep, your assumptions are right. Regarding memory the instrument is limited to 16 million lines of IQ data so will never be more than that.There are C libraries for the data capture itself and instument control. I was going to move on to using these and dragging the data straight into the app later, but I haven't read the huge amount of documentation for that bit yet. It'll still be useful to make this work with already required

Comment: - acquired data too though, so I figured I'd do this first without specialist HW, then when it works move onto that later. :)

Comment: Regarding memory the instrument is limited to 16 million lines of IQ data so will never be more than that. So I guess 256 MB just for that? 16 million * 8 bytes (double) * 2 (I + Q values)? Then another 128 MB for time and 128 MB for ampltiude, but once ran and reduced I can shrink memory usage after?

Comment: Basically my thinking. That's a lot of memory, but still within the capacity of many PCs. An older machine may have difficulty, or the problem could grow bigger in the future and outgrow a powerful PC, of course. You may not need to store time in the array, as this could be computed as needed from the index and sampling rate.